# jQuery - hide a element inside a html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a ajax function that retrieves some data as html.

How can I hide a certain element from this html string? `$(data).find(".element").hide()` doesn't work...

Comment: What do you mean by hide? Did you append the HTML to the document yet? If not, then you'll need to do that *before* trying to hide the inner html node.

Comment: Are you storing it again afterwards?  Could do with seeing the contents of data, to make sure element is locatable within it.

Comment: @Timothy Not true.  http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/4X4RY/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it doesn't work? A common mistake is to assume that the string itself is modified.

Try this instead:

```
var $data = $(data); // create new DOM elements, and keep a reference to them
$data.find(".element").hide();  // find and hide .element
$data.appendTo('wherever');  // append the new elements
```

Another possibility is that the `.element` is at the *top level* of the of the HTML that was returned.

If that's the case you'd need the [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method  instead of the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method .

```
var $data = $(data); // create new DOM elements, and keep a reference to them
$data.filter(".element").hide();  // filter and hide .element
$data.appendTo('wherever');  // append the new elements
```

Last thing to try would be wrapping the entire HTML in a `<div>` element, then doing a `.find()`.

```
// var $data = $('<div>' + data + '</div>');  // original version
var $data = $('<div>').append( data );   // this may be better. not sure.
$data.find(".element").hide();
$data.children().appendTo('wherever');
```

Comment: thank you very much (ps only the version with `filter()` works for me)

Comment: @Alexandra: You're welcome. That means the `.element` is not nested. The `.find()` method only looks at descendants of the elements at the top. I'm a little surprised that the last solution wouldn't work though. I'll update it to what may be a better solution.